# How to render a date from integer values of day, month, year?

Tags: haskell

```
module Date where

type Date = (Int,Int,Int)

showDate :: Date -> String
showDate (d,m,y) = undefined --TODO
```

Inputing `showDate (1,1,2001)` should output `"1st January, 2001"`

Anyone know how I could go about this? I have an idea, just not sure how to tackle it.

Update:

```
toMonth :: Int -> String
toMonth x = case x of
1 -> "January"
2 -> "February"
3 -> "March"
4 -> "April"
5 -> "May"
6 -> "June"
7 -> "July"
8 -> "August"
9 -> "September"
10 -> "October"
11 -> "November"
12 -> "December"
otherwise -> "error"
```

Comment: Well if you have an idea, wouldn't it make sense to share it?

Comment: I believe you would need to create a case for each variable in (d,m,y). But I'm not sure how I could go about it.

Comment: Here's an idea: write functions `toMonth :: Int -> String`, and `toOrdinal :: Int -> String`, then bring them together. Do you think you could do that?

Comment: @goat: can you explain why you think every variable needs a case?

Comment: @AJFarmar I did the toMonth function, I edited the code above, but not sure what the toOrdinal function is supposed to do? 

WillemVanOnsem, Because the users input would need to match a day,month,year? As in, in the case of a user inputting 1, the month would be January.

Comment: Idea for `toOrdinal`: if you `mod` a integer by 10, you can get the last digit of the number. You can make an another case for the last number, which maps integer(1, 2, 3, ..) to suffix(st, nd, rd, ..).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, always watch out with indentation.

```
toMonth x = case x of
             1 -> "January"
             2 -> "February"
             3 -> "March"
             ...
```

(You don't need that much indentation, just one space to the right of the `toMonth` would also do; but I like indenting case clauses to one more than the `case` keyword itself.)

It's often more straightforward to not use the `case` construct but just a couple of function clauses, like

```
toMonth 1 = "January"
toMonth 2 = "February"
toMonth 3 = "March"
...
```

This is a matter of taste.

For the error case: you can't use `otherwise` here because you're using *pattern matching*. `otherwise` is just a shorthand for `True`, it can thus be used in *boolean* conditions, i.e. in *guards*, but here you need string patterns. The catch-all pattern is `_`, not `otherwise`. Also, don't give *strings containing `error`* as the result. This is very confusing in practice. Instead, use the standard `error` function, which crashes the program with a helpful message of where things went awry. (This being an exception that can be caught and handled by the main program if necessary.)

```
toMonth 12 = "December"
toMonth _ = error "Month number must be in range 1-12."
```

An alternative approach that's less verbose (though also rather less robust) is to just take the month names from a single string, like

```
toMonth n
  | n>0 && n<13  = names !! (n-1)
  | otherwise    = error "Month number must be in range 1-12."
 where names = words $ "January February March April May June July"
                    ++ " August September October November December"
```

This isn't really worthwhile here, but this idiom is much more sensible when you don't just have 12 cases but hundreds. Then you should also store the names not in a list but a [`Vector`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.0.1/docs/Data-Vector.html#t:Vector) for faster lookup.

So, once you have written and tested `toMonth`, you can use it in `showDate` like this:

```
showDate (d,m,y) = toDayNumber d ++ " " ++ toMonth m ++ ", " ++ toYear y
```

Where you still need to implement `toDayNumber :: Int -> String` and `toYear :: Int -> String`. You should again think about that yourself, first.